# I am no longer able to see logs and health tabs in Firebase Cloud Functions console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-console

[image]

As shown in the attached picture the console & tabs are no longer there! How can I restore them?

Comment: Release notes: https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#cloud-functions-for-firebase

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those 2 tabs have been removed from Firebase console and a notice for the same was shown last month. You need to use the [Google Cloud Functions](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list) console to view functions' logs and statistics.

[image]

Firebase console now shows the follow alert once:

[image]

Comment: I really wouldn't call them "Improved view"..

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can log into the Firebase Console, go to the functions menu, and from the overflow icon displayed for each function, navigate to see its log (see the *view logs* option). It will save you some time.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes I know that I can view logs from there, the thing is it's longer being opened via firebase instead it redirects you to the google cloud logs.

As mentioned in the answer above firebase log console is no longer available

Comment: That's good for you @MoathThawahreh! Others still mighty be wondering where to get access to the logs from the Firebase Console and spend a reasonable time till they find it can be done through the overflow menu. Hope this answer help these people.